# how chainlink aggregates

Tags: chainlink

How does chainlink result aggregation work?

Are all oracle nodes that user-specified reports the results to the smart contract that chainlink is submitted on Ethereum? Is taking a median off aggregated results happens on the chainlink smart contract?

or

"watchdog" is the one that is selected randomly aggregates the result on off-chain and reports them to on-chain?

Answer (score 0):

Edit Revised:

The aggregation happens off-chain now that OCR (off-chain reporting) is implemented. So your second scenario with the single node reporting all the individual data points and aggregating them would be correct.

You can view the [blog post on OCR here.](https://blog.chain.link/off-chain-reporting-live-on-mainnet/)

Comment: I don't think its correct. If the results are aggregated on smart contract, how to catch if oracle node is lying? Here is an article saying that it is aggragated by a node which sends them to aggregate smart contract: https://medium.com/chorus-one/chainlink-2-0-super-linear-staking-economics-explained-4ba482202e9a

Comment: Here is another medium from chainlink that is telling aggregation happens off-chain.